# Magento 2 Edit Product page Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, eav-attributes, product-edit

I'm using magento 2.2.5 and when i opened the edit product page the product name, price,etc doesnt load at all, and when i checked the `var/log/exception.log` i got the following error:

> Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own
>   alias, query was: SELECT `u`.* FROM (SELECT `t`.`value`,
>   `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM
>   `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '6144') AND
>   (attribute_id IN ('75', '76', '79', '91', '80', '120', '99')) AND
>   (`store_id` IN (0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`,
>   `t`.`store_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t` WHERE
>   (entity_id = '6144') AND (attribute_id IN ('82', '85', '122', '103',
>   '71', '86', '192', '84', '87', '88', '107', '95', '109', '119', '222',
>   '236', '237', '238', '239', '240', '241', '242', '244', '245', '98',
>   '112', '113', '97', '114', '117', '215', '129', '216', '130', '217',
>   '218', '219', '220')) AND (`store_id` IN (0)))UNION ALL(SELECT
>   `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM
>   `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '6144') AND
>   (attribute_id IN ('100', '127', '163', '89', '191', '167', '92',
>   '121', '171', '126', '173', '81', '96', '185', '234', '176', '177',
>   '102', '161', '123', '124', '125', '213', '128', '131', '153')) AND
>   (`store_id` IN (0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`, `t`.`attribute_id`,
>   `t`.`store_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t` WHERE
>   (entity_id = '6144') AND (attribute_id IN ('104', '77', '105', '78',
>   '93', '94')) AND (`store_id` IN (0)))UNION ALL(SELECT `t`.`value`,
>   `t`.`attribute_id`, `t`.`store_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text`
>   AS `t` WHERE (entity_id = '6144') AND (attribute_id IN ('83', '101',
>   '72', '106', '73', '162', '164', '169')) AND (`store_id` IN (0))) AS
>   `u` ORDER BY `store_id` ASC